# add different texts to textarea by button - not working

Tags: javascript, textarea

I'm afraid I'm still lacking fundamental knowledge about JS. I'm learning but I'm not there yet at all:

Still, I'm trying to get different buttons to add different texts into a textarea (see http://jsfiddle.net/ctW65/). These are my buttons:

```
<input id="insertPattern1" type="button" value="1" click="insertAtTextareaCursor('insertPattern1', 'a'" />
<input id="insertPattern2" type="button" value="2" click="insertAtTextareaCursor('insertPattern2', 'b'" />
```

This would be my function:

```
$(function () {

$('input#insertPattern1').click(function () {
    insertAtTextareaCursor('insertPattern1', 'a');
});
```

The first thing is that if only one the first button is present it puts in text into the box. The moment I add the second button it just stops doing anything. What's my mistake here? The second question is presumably so fundamental I'm almost ashamed to ask: How do I get the function to add whatever text is in the button's value (there will be many buttons)?

Thank you so much for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your html, you need to call your event onclick.
Second, you forgot to close the ) like this:

```
<input id="insertPattern2" type="button" value="2" onclick="insertAtTextareaCursor('insertPattern2', 'b')" />
```

Your second submit is working, but the first is not.

You don't need to add this code:

```
$('input#insertPattern1').click(function () {
    insertAtTextareaCursor('insertPattern1', 'a');
});
```

Because you already bind the button to the click event in the html

You can look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/ctW65/4/), the second button is working.

EDIT: I updated the fiddle to show you how to pass the value of the control, just pass 'this' instead of 'aText' and in your function, declare your variable text like this:

```
var text = control.value;
```

Because you're now passing the control, you have access to it's value.

Comment: Thanks for helping, Shryme! It's very curious with these buttons. It seems only the last button works, no matter their name (I added another button at the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ctW65/5/)). Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/ctW65/6/) It looks like the problem is when you are declaring your var textarea, I'm not familiar with jquery, so I did it in javascript and it's working now!

Comment: Thank you so much, Shryme! That did the trick. All the best to you, and again thanks for helping and explaining.